# How to prevent the user from going back to login page when hardware back button is tapped, once he's logged in in Ionc4 app?

Tags: angular6, router, ionic4, back-button

I am developing Ionic4 App. So first I have Welcome page, that has one button "Log in" that when clicked navigates to Log In Page (using this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/login')). When the user logs in, the Dashboard shows up using NavController in the login.ts

```
    login() {
        this.loginService.login().subscribe(user => {

            this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/dashboard');

        });
    }
```

On dashboard I register the back button in the constructor:

```
    this.platform.backButton.subscribe( () => {

            if(this.router.url=='/dashboard')
                this.presentBackButtonAlert();
        }
    );
```

When the button is clicked an alert shows up to confirm if the user wants to exit the app:

```
     presentBackButtonAlert() {
        this.alertCtrl.presentAlert({
            header: 'Exit?',
            buttons: [
              {
                text: 'No',
                role: 'cancel',
                handler: () => {
                }

              }, {
                text: 'Yes',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Confirm Okay');
                    navigator['app'].exitApp();
                }
              }
            ]

        });
     }
```

The problem is when I tap the hardware back button, the alert shows up but the Dashboard Page navigates back to Welcome Page.

I expect that when I am logged in (on Dashboard Page), and tap the back button, only the alert to appear without navigating back.

Here's my AuthGuard:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import {AuthService} from '../authentication/auth.service';
    import {CanActivate} from '@angular/router';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate{

        constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

        canActivate(): boolean {
            return this.authService.isAuthenticated();
        }

  }
```

And this is how I use it on the router module:

```
    {path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/Auth/login/login.module#LoginPageModule', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './pages/company/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule', canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
```

My authState is in the AuthService and it looks like this:

```
     public authState = new BehaviorSubject(false);
     public isAuthenticated() {
        return this.authState.value;
     }
```

Comment: You should store the current user using any proffered method. ( Such as local storage for instance). Then use a Router Guard to manage routing to the page you don't want access too

Comment: I followed this tutorial for the guard but still it's the same.

Comment: Can you add the code for your Guard ?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: Does isAuthenticated simply give a boolean value to wether you are logged in or not ?

Comment: yes I will update the code again. And I set it to true only when I get positive response from backend

Answer (score 0):

The first is that simply returning the Boolean value isn't enough in a Guard. You should also tell to which page you want to go to if the condition held by the Guard isn't met
so you canActivate Method

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from '../authentication/auth.service';
import {CanActivate} from '@angular/router';
import { Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate{

    constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        if(this.authService.isAuthenticated()){
            this.router.navigate(['/whateverpage'])
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

You should also add the gaurd to the page you are about to go to. Since you want to prevent access to the login page after a user has logged in the guard should be added to the loginpage

```
 {path: 'login', loadChildren: './pages/Auth/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
 {path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './pages/company/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule'},
```

Comment: The pages you want to go to should be navigated to as required.

Comment: Still when I'm logged in and tap back it takes me to WelcomePage and that mustn't happen.

Comment: Seems like there is another error in your implementation I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

**For Ionic4, I tried this method and it is working fine for me.**

**Back button after login page means the user wants to exit the application or navigate to other paths.**

> When the view is entering I am subscribing it variable and when it leaves then unsubscribe. So that the exiting app on the back button will execute for that particular page only(e.g. dashboard page).

```
constructor(private platform: Platform){}
backButtonSubscription;
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.backButtonSubscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
  navigator['app'].exitApp();
  // edit your code here
  // either you exit or navigate to the desired path
  });
 }
}
ionViewDidLeave() {
 this.backButtonSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the question and answers, they guided me in the right way because I was facing a similar challenge, in my case, I fixed this doing something as follows on the canActivate() method on my Guard class, then I added this canActivate only to the auth page config on the app-routing.module.ts, (the rest of the pages use the canLoad instead):

```js
  canLoad(
    route: Route,
    segments: UrlSegment[]): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    return this.authService.UserIsAuthenticated.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          return this.authService.autoLogin();
        } else {
          return of(isAuthenticated);
        }
      }),
      tap(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/auth');
        }
      }));
  }

  canActivate(
    route: import("@angular/router").ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: import("@angular/router").RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | import("@angular/router").UrlTree | Observable<boolean |
      import("@angular/router").UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | import("@angular/router").UrlTree> {
    return this.authService.UserIsAuthenticated.pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          return this.authService.autoLogin();
        } else {
          return of(isAuthenticated);
        }
      }),
      map(isAuthenticated => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
          return false;
        }
      }));
  }
```

So on the routing config, I only used the canActivate for the auth page...

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', redirectTo: 'auth', pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthPageModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsPageModule',
        canLoad: [AuthGuard]
      },
      {
        path: 'new',
        loadChildren: './products/new-product/new-product.module#NewProductPageModule',
        canLoad: [AuthGuard]
      },
      .....
```